# How to use a vector when indexing columns?

Tags: r

So basically, I have a vector:

Note, thetitanic is a data frame of the people who attended the titanic.

```
femalesurvivors_1 <- thetitanic[(thetitanic$Sex=="female") & (thetitanic$Survived==1) & (thetitanic$PClass=="1st"),]
```

This shows the female survivors of the 1st class. However, now I only want the female survivors of the 1st class who are above 18 years of age. So:

I want to also index `(thetitanic$Sex>=18)`

I have been trying some forms of code but I keep getting errors.
`x <- thetitanic[(femalesurvivors_1) & (thetitanic$Age>=18)]`

The error shows: 1: In Ops.factor(left, right) : '&' not meaningful for factors

Am I able to pass through a vector when doing? Or would I have to make a new vector and repeat code?

I am trying to return the value of female survivors in the 1st class, who are above 18 years age.

I am a noob.. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You might want to share a bit more information, like what the data looks like, which error messages you're getting, and perhaps most importantly, what does your expected outcome look like?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a logical vector of conditions and take `sum` over it.

```
sum(with(thetitanic, 
    Survived == 1 & Sex == "female" & Pclass == 1 & Age >= 18), na.rm = TRUE)
```

Using `subset`

```
nrow(subset(thetitanic, Survived == 1 & Sex == "female" & Pclass == 1 & Age >= 18))
```

Or with `dplyr` using `filter`

```
library(dplyr)

thetitanic %>%
  filter(Survived == 1 & Sex == "female" & Pclass == 1 & Age >= 18) %>%
   nrow
```

This will return number of female survivors of 1st class above age of 18. If you want those entries then remove `nrow` from `filter` and `subset` functions.

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
nrow(setDT(thetitanic)[Survived == 1 & Sex == "Female" & Pclass == 1 & Age >= 18])
```